# Forge Viewer property database userFunction not found due to Vue webpack mangling (terser)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, terser

I am using a `userFunction` to query the property database in a custom Forge Viewer extension. This works great while testing the site locally using `npm run serve`. However, when I deploy the website to the web (which uses `npm run build`), the function no longer executes. The error says: `SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`. This is because, according to the documentation, the function executed through `executeUserFunction` *has* to be named `userFunction`.

Upon further inspection I discovered that this was because of Vue & Webpack's mangling feature (executed by `terser-webpack-plugin`), where it renames variables and removes function names to decrease file size.

I have tried many different things, from making the function part of the extension's class to moving it to the global JS scope, but nothing helped. I also tried to exclude `objects.js` (which is the name of the extension I wrote) from mangling, but this didn't work either.

How do I configure terser to stop mangling this one variable?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out a way to do this which worked:

Add the following to `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap(args => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      args[0].terserOptions.keep_fnames = true;
      return args;
    });
  },
};
```

This will prevent terser from removing function names, and will make it so `userFunction` still works. Weird design choice by Autodesk to require a function name, but at least it works now :)